# Converting Date Into words and displaying using visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to convert date in words as shown below:
10/07/2014

TENTH Day of JULY, TWO
THOUSAND FOURTEEN

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Can you use apex?

Comment: Date presentDate = new Date();
String value = String.valueOf(presentDate);

Comment: Yes i can use apex

Comment: Apex [Date](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) has methods to get a number for each part of the date; you then just need several Map<Integer, String> to translate the parts to strings (though the year part will probably need building in pieces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the string up in VF by something like the following. Just replace the variable today() with whatever value you need. You'll also need to fill in the extra day values, and also the years.

Note: The month comes out as July. If you need JULY then you may need to create another block of statements similar to the DAY block with the correct case included.

```
<apex:outputText value="FIRST" rendered="{!Day(today()) == 1}"/>
   <apex:outputText value="SECOND" rendered="{!Day(today()) == 2}"/>
   <apex:outputText value="THIRD" rendered="{!Day(today()) == 3}"/>
   <apex:outputText value="TWENTY SECOND" rendered="{!Day(today()) == 22}"/>

   &nbsp;DAY of <apex:outputText value="{0, DATE, MMMM}"><apex:param value="{!today()}" name="month"/></apex:outputText>

   , TWO THOUSAND&nbsp;
   <apex:outputText value="FOURTEEN" rendered="{!YEAR(today()) == 2014}"/>
   <apex:outputText value="FIFTEEN" rendered="{!YEAR(today()) == 2015}"/>
   <apex:outputText value="SIXTEEN" rendered="{!YEAR(today()) == 2016}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but need to fetch date field and then display instead of todays date.

Comment: Add a standard controller to the page and then pull in the field from the object; or use a custom apex controller. You should be able to find examples in the docs and/or internet.